# Fetching rougly 7Mb of data from SQL server 2008 R2 to a client takes around 5 seconds. Why is it so slow, is it normal?

Tags: sql, performance, select

Fetching rougly 7Mb of data from SQL server 2008 R2 to a client takes around 5 seconds. The machine is relatively powerful AMD 12 Core, 64Gb RAM, Windows Server 2008, 2 10Gbit cards.
Running the select on the server is even slower, then from client. Copying 7Mb file from that server to a local workstation is around 500ms.

Here is a small reproducer:

```
--create test table for reproducer
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Speed](
    [ED] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

  --fill test table with data, insert took 3:51 mins
  declare @r int
  set @r = 1
  while (@r < 830000)
  begin 
  insert into [CDB_ODS].[dbo].[Test_Speed] select getdate()
  set @r = @r+1
  end

  --select all records, roughly 7Mb. 4 secs if run on the client, 5 secs on the server (1.4Mb sec)
  select ed from [dbo].[Test_Speed]


  /*
  SELECT on CLIENT
    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1833, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, 
lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 281 ms,  elapsed time = 4020 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.


   --- SELECT on SERVER 
   SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(829999 row(s) affected)
Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1833, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
 lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 328 ms,  elapsed time = 5369 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

   */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this seems relatively normal to me.  7Mbytes is a fair amount of data.

Performance depends highly on the client.  Of course, things like network speed have an effect.  A bigger effect is buffer sizes at various points along the way.  For fastest performance, you want SQL Server to send over big batches of results all at once, which get quickly put into the application.

Other options have a big effect as well.  In Excel/VBA, there are different methods of bringing data in.  If you use a cursor, you want a read-only, read forward cursor.  Anything else can be much, much slower.  One kind of cursor, for instance, will read the data one row at a time -- so latency becomes the dominant factor in performance rather than bandwidth (I think this is updatable cursors, but I'm not positive).

You'll need to say more about your client and how it accesses the data.  This is most likely a client side issue and not a database issue.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. my suspicion is too that the client can't "digest" the data fast enough. Client in this test case is the MS SQL Management Studio 2008, or a .NET 4.0 application. What would be another alternative to pull out this amout of data faster?

Answer (score 0):

Primary key, index seek, index scan, execution plan, those are your friends here. [Check this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/) for index subject. This [forum post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1296026-1291-1.aspx) can help too on understanding primary and foreign keys. An about execution plan analysis and understanding check out [this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

On databases I work and have worked retrieving similar amount of information, thousands of rows, take less than a second. Is very important to take into account your database design and later improve performance tweaking the queries by testing different approaches, not always throwing more CPU/RAM power is the best way

EDITED

I feel some irony on your comment, hope is not your goal. Be my guest using the following tests I have just done (impossible do it before, now I'm off duty hours). Inserts in my case are around 20-30s as I used far better approach (CTE) to insert near 1 million rows. Comparing times you will see that using primary key is little bit more than 1s faster than not using it. Also on server was in general 1s second faster.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Speed]([ED] [DATETIME2] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Idx1 ON Test_Speed(ED);

DECLARE @firstdate DATETIME2='00010101 00:00:00', 
        @lastdate DATETIME2= '25001231 00:00:00'

;WITH CTE_DatesTable
  AS
  (
    SELECT @FirstDate AS auxDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, auxDate)
    FROM CTE_DatesTable
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, auxDate) <= @LastDate
  )
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Speed]
  SELECT auxDate FROM CTE_DatesTable
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

  SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
  SET STATISTICS IO ON;
  SELECT ED FROM [dbo].[Test_Speed]
  SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
  SET STATISTICS IO OFF;



/*
    Select on Client with primary key , insertion 21s
    (913106 row(s) affected)
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
    (913106 row(s) affected)
    Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1919, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 375 ms,  elapsed time = 7790 ms   

    Select on Client without primary key , insertion 31s   
    SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
    (913106 row(s) affected)
    Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1931, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    (1 row(s) affected)
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 405 ms,  elapsed time = 8049 ms.

    ------------------  

    Select on Server with Primary key, insertion 19s
    (913106 row(s) affected)
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
    (913106 row(s) affected)
    Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1931, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 187 ms,  elapsed time = 6164 ms.   

    Select on Server without Primary key, insertion 25s
     (913106 row(s) affected)
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
    (913106 row(s) affected)
    Table 'Test_Speed'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1919, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 343 ms,  elapsed time = 7407 ms.
*/
```

Comment: did you see the reproducer code? it's a table with one column. putting a key on top of it doesn't improve the matters.

Comment: can you please try the reproducer code on "one of the databases you work"? thanks.

Comment: Yaroslav, many thanks for trying out. No irony, just trying to get to the bottom of this. Looks like selects are between 6-8 secs on your machine for this test case? Any reflections how these could be brought down to less than 1 sec? 
Дякую!

Comment: See that I made tests on my pc and on our server, is not a top edge server, is a regular dual Xeon some years old with 8Gb RAM and Raid 1 with 2 SCSI 75Gb hard drives. I did not had time to run more tests or make a deeper analisys of the execution plan to see more differences. What I indeed noticed is that in fact with primary key is about one second faster on both cases, my pc and server. I ran several tests with client statistics active and each time got same results, bit faster with primary key....ni sa shto...offtopic: are you ukranian?